# SFTP Outbound Gateway Commands

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I need to use more commands (cd, mkdir, rmdir) with `SFTPOutboundGateway`, but according to [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway), there is only a handful of commands available, none of the other ones I need being included. Is there a reason behind it ? Is there a(nother) way to use more commands such as cd, mkdir and rmdir ?

Answer (score 1):

`cd` in a gateway makes no sense since it effectively would do nothing.

For commands not supported by the gateway, use the `SftpRemoteFileGateway` from your code in a service activator.

For commands not supported by the template, use

```
/**
 * Execute the callback's doInSession method after obtaining a session.
 * Reliably closes the session when the method exits.
 *
 * @param callback the SessionCallback.
 * @param <T> The type returned by
 * {@link SessionCallback#doInSession(org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.Session)}.
 * @return The result of the callback method.
 */
<T> T execute(SessionCallback<F, T> callback);
```

and

@FunctionalInterface
public interface SessionCallback {

```
/**
 * Called within the context of a session.
 * Perform some operation(s) on the session. The caller will take
 * care of closing the session after this method exits.
 *
 * @param session The session.
 * @return The result of type T.
 * @throws IOException Any IOException.
 */
T doInSession(Session<F> session) throws IOException;
```

}

For commands not supported by `Session`, use

```
/**
 * Get the underlying client library's client instance for this session.
 * Returns an {@code Object} to avoid significant changes to -file, -ftp, -sftp
 * modules, which would be required
 * if we added another generic parameter. Implementations should narrow the
 * return type.
 * @return The client instance.
 * @since 4.1
 */
Object getClientInstance();

@Override
public ChannelSftp getClientInstance() {
    return this.channel;
}
```

and operate on the JSch client directly.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use those the best way I can. But out of curiosity, why is it that rmdir, mkdir for instance are not available via ```SftpOutboundGateway``` ?

Comment: Simply that nobody asked for them before. Typically, commands like that would be used as part of some larger sequence and a Spring Integration flow might not be the best way to achieve that.